# Validating a form using JSP

Tags: java, jsp, nullpointerexception

I'm completely new to JSP and am creating a simple form and validating it through JSP.
Here's my code :-

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<%@page import="java.io.* , java.sql.* , java.util.* , javax.servlet.*" %>

<body>
    <h1>Login Page by JSP</h1>
    <hr>
    <form method="post" action="index_jsp">
        Enter name : <input type="text" name="user">
        Enter password : <input type="password" name="pass">
        <input type="submit" value="login">
    </form>
    <%
    String user = request.getParameter("user");
    String pass = request.getParameter("pass");

    if(user.equals("admin") && pass.equals("admin"))
    {
    response.sendRedirect("wel.html");
    }

    %>
    <br>
    <a href="new.jsp">Click here !</a>

</body>
</html>
```

But each and every time I run it , I get a NullPointerException .
What am I doing wrong ? Immediate help would be appreciated !

Thanks!

Comment: Where exactly do you get the NPE? TBH, I didn't examine the code since it would be more time consuming to find the problem than to suggest a solution if we know where the problem is. :)

Comment: **Don't write Java code inside JSP**. If you are following some tutorial, stop right now. Don't learn things which are for more than a decade considered to be bad.

Answer (score 2):

First bit of advice, since you're new to JSP: Don't write scriptlet code.  That's all the stuff between `<%` and `%>`.  It's a 1998 vintage technology that should be discouraged.  Learn [JSTL](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-135995.html) and Model-2 MVC instead.

You need a servlet to orchestrate those JSPs.  Every web MVC framework that I know of has what's called a front controller servlet to manage the communication and orchestration.  You should, too.

You have the form POST in this JSP, sending the HTTP request to index_jsp (bad name).  It's executing in the browser on the client machine.

I would expect you to send this to a servlet on the server side that gets the HTTP request, gets the username and password out, compares the values to a database to see if the user is indeed registered.  Then I'd either send the next view or route to the "sorry" page.  That's not what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do equals checks on the variables, rather do them against the constants:

```
 if("admin".equals(user) && "admin".equals(pass)) {
    response.sendRedirect("wel.html");
 }
```

This way you cannot get the NPE.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
if(user.equals("admin") && pass.equals("admin"))
    {
    response.sendRedirect("wel.html");
    }
```

with

```
if(user!=null){

    if(user.equals("admin") && pass.equals("admin"))
    {
    response.sendRedirect("wel.html");
    }
}
```

Comment: you are getting null in user variable. Also accept answer and upvote as well.

Answer (score 0):

You are not checking null for request attributes.

replace

```
String user = request.getParameter("user");
String pass = request.getParameter("pass");
```

with

```
String user = request.getParameter("user") != null ? request.getParameter("user") : "";
String pass = request.getParameter("pass") != null ? request.getParameter("pass") : "";
```

Answer (score 0):

change code：

```
if("admin".equals(user) && "admin".equals(pass))  {
    response.sendRedirect("wel.html");
}
```

When you first run jsp,it will execute the code,but user and pass is null.